# JSON / JSONP - works with local json file but not from live external URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, getjson

I have a scenario whereby I am needing to display some fairly simple data (using JQUERY) from an external web app my client is providing that serves up well formatted json (validated using jsonlint.com).  this is my first time using json and when I use dataType jsonp and the LIVE url I get an 'invalid label' error on the first quote in the beginning of the name:value pairs in the JSON data... but when I copy that same json and save it locally and change jsonp to just json, it works and I can manipulate the data any way I want in the DOM and accomplish what Im after.

what do I need to do to get the live URL json to work?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>JSON Test</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
type : 'GET',
//url : 'jsondata2.js',
url: 'http://.....'    //MY LIVE URL HERE.   NOTE, THE LOCAL FILE ABOVE THAT DOES WORK (JSON NOT JSONP) IS JUST A COPY/PASTE OF THE DATA THAT THIS URL DISPLAYS IN BROWSER.  ,
dataType : 'jsonp',
success : function(jsonData) {
alert(jsonData.PropertyName);
},
error : function() {
alert('Error loading the JSON data');
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Heres the json data:

```
{
"PropertyID": 1468,
"PropertyName": "AG Test One",
"Listing Information": {
    "Availability": "Not Specified",
    "Pricing Information": "For Sale, Price: 1.00 (Set Price per Acre)"
},
"Location": {
    "City": "ZZ",
    "County": "ZZ Test County",
    "Municipality": "Within City Limits",
    "State": "SC",
    "Tax Map ID": "123-123-123",
    "ZipCode": "22222"
},
"Physical Details": {
    "Certified Property": false,
    "Minimum Divisible Acreage": 0,
    "Site Comments": null,
    "Site Improvements": "Forested",
    "Surrounding Land Use": [
        "North: Airport / Port / Intermodal Facility",
        "South: Waterway (River / Lake)",
        "East: Utility (Easements / Substations)",
        "West: Correctional Facility"
    ],
    "Total Site Size": 500,
    "Zoning": null
},
"Transportation": {
    "Barge Access": false,
    "Name of Rail Carrier Providing Service": "None specified",
    "Nearest Commercial Airport": "None Specified",
    "Nearest Interstate": "None Specified",
    "Nearest Sea Port": "None Specified",
    "Railway Access": false,
    "Runway Access": false
},
"Utilities": {
    "Diameter of Waste Water Main": 0,
    "Diameter of Water Main": 0,
    "Distance To Electric Provider": 1,
    "Distance to Natural Gas Provider": 0,
    "Distance to Sewer Service": 0,
    "Distance to Water Service": 0,
    "Electric Provider": "Undetermined",
    "Fire Insurance Rating": "1",
    "Natural Gas Provider": null,
    "Telecommunications Providers": null,
    "Type of Sewer": "",
    "Water Service Provider": "Undetermined",
    "Water Water Service Provider": "Undetermined"
}
}
```

I also tried getJSON method... and get same reults in both local and external url scenarios:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.getJSON('jsondata2.js', function(data) {
                //$.getJSON('SAME LIVE URL HERE....', function(data) {
                var output = "<ul>";
                output += "<li>" + data.PropertyName + "</li>";
                output += "</ul>";
                document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For JSONP your server needs to output

```
callback(JSONSTRING)
```

and not just the JSON string! jQuery will automatically execute this Javascript code using the success callback of $.ajax()

Comment: ah, i see.  thanks.   question:  is it possible to get the contents of the live url (just raw json NOT wrapped in callback() as you noted), use that as a local variable to parse write out in browser?  if that makes sense.   i will try to see if the folks running the web service can add the callback() to it... the data is being provided to a number of other developers besides myself so perhaps this is something that ultimately they'll have to do for all the sites that will use the data?  or are there other methods that wouldnt require it that I need to research?

Comment: Either the server needs to return the JSON like `callback(JSON)` or it must send back a response header with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` pointing to your origin URL (or `*` if every calling origin should be covered). For the latter you'll have to change to dataType "json" instead of "jsonp"